# Fitting data that follows specific equation

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

Given the following equation:

$y = \frac{80-x}{100-x}$

If I had real world data that followed this exact equation, how would I back out an equation to always predict the correct $y$ value given an $x$ value?

A second degree polynomial comes close but is not exact. I would hope for the resulting equation to be simple, given the simplicity of the equation to generate the data.

Sample Data:
x, y
0.000,  0.800
10.000, 0.778
20.000, 0.750
30.000, 0.714
40.000, 0.667
50.000, 0.600
60.000, 0.500
70.000, 0.333
80.000, 0.000

Comment: Why not just plug it into the original equation of $\frac{80-x}{100-x}$?

Comment: I'm hoping to understand how I would arrive at the equation if I only had the data.

Comment: You would need to know what "format" the original equation is in (i.e. $\frac{a-x}{b-x}$). Otherwise, you could always fit a polynomial to the data.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Can you joint to your question a representative example of data and say what you expect to get from the data.

Comment: I added sample data based on the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=\frac{ax+b}{x+c}\quad\implies\quad xy=-cy+ax+b$$
Approximate $a,b,c$ are computed thanks to linear regression :

[image]

The above method is valid because no criteria of fitting is specified in the question.

If a particular criteria of fitting was requiered non-linear regression should be necessary. But the result would be very close to the above result because the data is  almost not scattered.